# Requisição Ajax com dados vindo de outro Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Eu tenho um Ajax. que busca informações do **receitaws**
esse ajax trás o endereço e tbm o CEP.
E eu tenho outro Ajax, que tras informações de endereço, através do CEP, 
um em particular, que eu preciso, que é o Código do Muncipio.

Então eu queria fazer assim, ao pesquisar o CNPJ, carregar os dados vindo do `receiraWs` ao carregar os dados, ja automaticamente, fazer a outra requisição via CEP. assim, trazendo o Código do municipio.

Ou seja, se a consulta ao receitaws fosse bem sucessedida, no momento que tivesse carregando os dados, ao chegar no dado CEP, ja fizesse o segundo `ajax`

```js
   <script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Adicionamos o evento onclick ao botão com o ID "pesquisar"
    $('#pesquisar').on('click',
        function(e) {

            // Apesar do botão estar com o type="button", é prudente chamar essa função para evitar algum comportamento indesejado
            e.preventDefault();

            // Aqui recuperamos o cnpj preenchido do campo e usamos uma expressão regular para limpar da string tudo aquilo que for diferente de números
            var cnpj = $('#Cliente_Cnpj').val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

            // Fazemos uma verificação simples do cnpj confirmando se ele tem 14 caracteres
            
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/' + cnpj,
                                method: 'GET',
                                dataType:
                                    'jsonp', // Em requisições AJAX para outro domínio é necessário usar o formato "jsonp" que é o único aceito pelos navegadores por questão de segurança
                                beforeSend: function() {
                                    $('#status').html('<div class="alert alert-info">Buscando CNPJ</div>');
                                },

                                complete: function (xhr) {
                                    $('#status').html('<div class="alert alert-success">CNPJ Encontrado</div>');
                                    setTimeout(function() {
                                        $('#status').html('');
                                    }, 1000);

                                    // Aqui recuperamos o json retornado
                                    response = xhr.responseJSON;

                                    // Na documentação desta API tem esse campo status que retorna "OK" caso a consulta tenha sido efetuada com sucesso
                                    if (response.status == 'OK') {

                                        // Agora preenchemos os campos com os valores retornados
                                        $('#Cliente_RazaoSocial').val(response.nome);
                                        $('#Cliente_NomeFantasia').val(response.fantasia);
                                        $('#Endereco_Rua').val(response.logradouro);
                                        $('#Endereco_Numero').val(response.numero);
                                        $('#Endereco_Bairro').val(response.bairro);
                                        $("#Endereco_Cidade_Nome").val(response.municipio);
                                        $("#Endereco_Cidade_Estado_Uf").val(response.uf);
                                        $('#Endereco_Complemento').val(response.complemento);
                                        var cep = $('#Endereco_Cep').val(response.cep);
                                        cep.replace(".", "");
                                        $('#Endereco_Cep').val(cep);//aqui quero fazer a function para buscar o cep quando esse campo for carregado com dados

                                        //$('#Cliente_Cnae').val(response.atividade_principal);
                                        // Aqui exibimos uma mensagem caso tenha ocorrido algum erro
                                    } else {
                                        alert(response.message); // Neste caso estamos imprimindo a mensagem que a própria API retorna
                                    }

                                }
                            });
                     

                    }
                });

                // Tratativa para caso o CNPJ não tenha 14 caracteres
            
        });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

            function limpa_formulário_cep() {
                $("#Endereco_Cidade_Codigo").val("");
            }

            //Quando o campo cep perde o foco.
            $("#Endereco_Cep").blur(function() {

                //Nova variável "cep" somente com dígitos.
                var cep = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, '');

                //Verifica se campo cep possui valor informado.
                if (cep != "") {

                    //Expressão regular para validar o CEP.
                    var validacep = /^[0-9]{8}$/;

                    //Valida o formato do CEP.
                    if(validacep.test(cep)) {

                        //Preenche os campos com "..." enquanto consulta webservice.

                        $("#Endereco_Cidade_Codigo").val("...Procurando");

                        //Consulta o webservice viacep.com.br/
                        $.getJSON("https://viacep.com.br/ws/"+ cep +"/json/?callback=?", function(dados) {

                            if (!("erro" in dados)) {
                                //Atualiza os campos com os valores da consulta.
                             
                                $("#Endereco_Cidade_Codigo").val(dados.ibge);
                                
                            } //end if.
                            else {
                                //CEP pesquisado não foi encontrado.
                                limpa_formulário_cep();
                                alert("CEP não encontrado.");
                            }
                        });
                    } //end if.
                    else {
                        //cep é inválido.
                        limpa_formulário_cep();
                        alert("Formato de CEP inválido.");
                    }
                } //end if.
                else {
                    //cep sem valor, limpa formulário.
                    limpa_formulário_cep();
                }
            });
        });

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
<input class="form-control-sm" placeholde="CNPJ" id="Cliente_Cnpj" name="Cliente_Cnpj"  type="text" >
<a href="#" id="pesquisar" class="btn btn-small" style="padding: 0">
<i class="fa fa-search" style="color: #020204;">Pesquisar Cnpj</i>
</a>
<input class="form-control-sm id="Cliente_RazaoSocial" name="Cliente_RazaoSocial" placeholder="rAZÃO sOCIAL">

<input class="form-control-sm"  placeholder="Código Cidade" id="Endereco_Cidade_Codigo" name="Endereco_Cidade_Codigo">

<input class="form-control-sm " placeholder="CEP" id="Endereco_Cep" name="Endereco_Cep">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize os métodos abaixo para processar as chamadas:

```
$.getJSON("https://...", function(dados1) {
   // 1ª Chamada

})
.done(function(dados1) {
    console.log(dados1); // Dados retornados da primeira chamada

    $.getJSON("https://...", function(dados2) {
        // 2ª Chamada

    })
    .done(function(dados2) {
       console.log(dados2); // Dados retornados da segunda chamada
    })
    .fail(function() {
    })
    .always(function() {
    });
})
.fail(function() {
})
.always(function() {
});
```

Sempre observando quanto a conversão dos dados recebidos;

Segue documentação completa para maiores detalhes: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Desculpa, seu meio leigo, a primeira chamada, é a do receitaWs, a segunda é a do viaCep, esse método, eu coloco em um script separado, junto da primeira chamada Ajax?

Comment: Editei a resposta, talvez fique mais próximo do entendimento